# Neo4j web interface, make permanent custom scripts

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Neo4j allows to save scripts used in the web interface, or import them (one at a time) from file (Drop Cypher script file to import).
The issue, these scripts disapear when neo4j is stopped and I have to import them one by one.

Is there a way to make those script permanent in the interface?

[image]

Comment: They shouldn't not go away. They are stored in the browser, so next time you connect to neo4j they should still be there. If they are not, it's a bug.

Comment: What browser, OS do you use? How do you open your web browser URL?

Comment: (OS : Vista + Neo4j community 2.0.1)
                                                                  
1- I launch Neo4j community ==> 2- choose the database location ==> 3- start ==> 4- In browse: http://localhost:7474/browser/ ==> stop process ==> start the process again

Comment: browser = Google chrome.

Comment: After you start again, all the saved scripts are gone? Is there any setting in chrome that you activated (e.g. privacy) to clear out all site's activity? It is stored in browser local storage. You can see it in the developer-console-resources tab.

Comment: Indeed Michael, That was causing the issue: an eraser plugin with "full mode" was set (not a permanent machine). Is there a way to make that menu portable across machines?

Comment: It's planned to provide a cloud service that will store your scripts online. Stay tuned.